# Creating snapshot in ArcMap of layer to use for legend?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, arcgis-9.3, legend

I am trying to create a snapshot using FastStone Capture version 5.3 to be use for the legend because it is diffcult to match their color especially is you are using raster or transparent ?

How do I save the snapshot to file and then use that file for the legend ? Any suggest ?

I am using 9.3.1 SP3.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the question - can you clarify? You are using a screen capture software to take a screenshot? Is the screenshot of an existing legend? It sounds like you want to import a .jpg or other image file to use as a legend.

Comment: Yes, first you will need to create a rectange to copy the polygon fill box and then use the FastStone Capture software to capture a screenshot and save as a .bmp file and replace it with as a Picture Fill symbol.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To match colors from another image I use paint and the dropper tool will collect any "solid" color.
If it is not a solid color you will have to get close.
But here is the rest.

in the paint program when you collect a color from an image with the dropper tool.
You then go to the rgb settings.
Then in arcmap you can duplicate that rgb setting.
screenshots to come.

Comment: Thank you. I use FastStone Capture and got it what I need. But, I'll remember your suggest too. Have a good day.

Comment: "paint and the dropper tool" only on Windows 7 (not XP)

Comment: paint and dropper tools were on windows 3. I use xp now.

Answer (score 0):

I export out an area into a .pdf, take it into power point, crop the area making sure the outline is none and the background is white, then I export and save that to a bmp.  Works every time.  I use this a lot for imagery transparencies where I need to have that match what the map looks like.